# Bootstrap 5: Can not use utilities

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I have updated my project from Bootstrap 4.5 to Bootstrap 5. I did this by simply overwriting all the old bootstrap files with `npm install bootstrap@next`. Now I have the problem that I can't use the bootstrap utilities anymore. They just don't seem to be compiled into the stylesheet, even though they are imported.

My app.scss file:

```
@import "variables";

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

For example, if I now try to hide in element with `.d-none`, then this has no effect. The compiled stylesheet also does not contain a utility class.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is a change in file structure in BS5 (vs. BS4).

The `_utilities.scss` file now only creates a variable `$utilities` holding all the ... utilities.
Another file `utilities\_api.scss`, when compiled, generates the utility CSS.

For your case use:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Make sure to read the [docs on how the API works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/).

Comment: Why  is this not in the docs? Or did I miss that somewhere?

Comment: Same, I also don't know why it isn't in the docs. It's a pretty big change that should've been noted.

Answer (score 1):

In the last update you should use like this:

```
// Here is some overrided bootstrap variables.

@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// You can edit utilities here. Explained here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#using-the-api

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Also you can see tru order in the main `bootstrap.scss` file.

Answer (score 0):

Do what they say in Bootstrap doc.

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/utilities";


$utilities: map-merge(
   $utilities, (
       "border": map-merge(
          map-get($utilities, "border"), 
          ( responsive: true ), ),
        )
);

@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

always place your utilities before the bootstrap imported. and import the three files where also bootstrap mentioned in API.

Comment: This would be the answer if the OP were trying to define their own utility, but they're trying to use one that's already defined in the Bootstrap scss